# Getting all ancestors/ Super types of a descendent/ Sub type from table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hierarchy, recursive-query

I have a table with hierarchical data that looks like this:

| ObjectType | ObjectSubType |
| --- | --- |
| Everything | Solid |
| Solid | Solid |
| Solid | Metal |
| Metal | Metal |
| Metal | Iron |
| Iron | Iron |

I'm trying to get all the ancestors/supertypes of any given objectSubType.

so if I want all the parents of Iron, it would look something like this:
Iron, Metal, Solid, Everything

I've tried using recursion by referring [this](https://akki.ca/blog/mysql-adjacency-list-model-for-hierarchical-data-using-cte/)

recursion code:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  ancestorCategories  AS
  (
    SELECT ObjectType, ObjectSubType, 0 AS depth
      FROM ObjectTypeHierarchyTable
      WHERE ObjectType = "Iron"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.ObjectType, c.ObjectSubType, ac.depth - 2
      FROM ancestorCategories AS ac 
        JOIN ObjectTypeHierarchyTable AS c ON ac.ObjectSubType = c.ObjectType
  )
SELECT * FROM ancestorCategories;
```

This does not seem to work though (possibly missing a termination condition?) - I get this error message when trying it out on db-fiddle:

> Recursive query aborted after 1001 iterations. Try increasing @@cte_max_recursion_depth to a larger value.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `This does not seem to work` - what does this mean? Please share the exact error message or describe the unexpected behaviour!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't solve it using recursion but managed to use a WHILE loop and a temporary table to get all the ancestors:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_ancestors(IN value VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  -- create a temporary table to hold the ancestors, once and truncate it
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ancestors (
    ObjectType VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  );
  TRUNCATE TABLE ancestors;
  -- insert the initial value into the ancestors table
  INSERT INTO ancestors (ObjectType) VALUES (value);
  
  -- Loop until no more ancestors are found
  SET @new_rows = 1;
  SET @iterations = 0;
  SET @max_iterations = 100;
  WHILE (@new_rows > 0) AND (@iterations < @max_iterations) DO
      INSERT INTO ancestors (ObjectType)
      SELECT DISTINCT ObjectType
      FROM ObjectTypeHierarchyTable
      WHERE ObjectSubType IN (SELECT ObjectType FROM ancestors) 
      AND ObjectType NOT IN (SELECT ObjectType FROM ancestors);
      
      SET @new_rows = ROW_COUNT();
      SET @iterations = @iterations + 1;
  END WHILE;

  -- select the ancestors from the temporary table
  SELECT * FROM ancestors;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL get_ancestors('Metal');
```

A procedure is also being used to wrap the WHILE statement because WHILE statements can't be used directly.

Optionally `TEMPORARY` keyword can be used while creating the `ancestors` table depending on the type and version of MySQL(it works in PyMySQL which is my use-case).